# WHMCS invoicepdf.tpl and viewinvoice.tpl multiple currencies

Tags: whmcs

I need two currencies displayed on invoices, in a very basic way: `$total` should be displayed in default currency, followed by currency calculated using current exchange rate stored in `tblcurrencies` table, but I'm having trouble getting this to work.

So this line in `invoicepdf.tpl` and should look something like:

```
<td align="center">'.$total.' (€'. number_format($total/$exrate, 2, '.', '').')</td>
```

where `$exrate` is current exchange rate pulled from the database and stored in a variable. Probably something similar should be in `viewinvoice.tpl`.

Of course, there might be a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is seen here, no currency variable is available : http://docs.whmcs.com/PDF_Invoice_Customisation

So what you need to do is simply make a database call within viewinvoice.tpl and get the currency variable.

Other and simpler way is to use whmcs built-in functions described here(Formatting Currency seciton):
http://docs.whmcs.com/Useful_Functions_for_Devs